# Define a rectangle as alias property in QML

Tags: qt, qml, alias

I have designed a simple window using rectangle that has a header bar and main section in a qml file like MyWindow.qml:

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 300

    property alias title: txtTitle.text
    property alias color: backgroundItem.color

    Rectangle {
        id: backgroundItem
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightgreen"
        anchors.margins: 5

        Rectangle {
            id: headerBar
            width: parent.width
            height: 30
            color: Qt.darker(parent.color)

            Rectangle {
                id: rectTitle
                height: 20
                anchors.left: headerBar.left
                anchors.leftMargin: 10
                anchors.verticalCenter: headerBar.verticalCenter

                Text {
                    id: txtTitle
                    text: "Window"
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    color: "white"
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
                }
            } //rectTitle
        } //headerBar

        Rectangle {
            anchors.top: headerBar.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            Rectangle {
                id: rectMain

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I need place a rectangle instead of `rectMain` when I use `MyWindow` in my main.qml. That means:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200

    MyWindow {
        id: innerWindow
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightgreen"
        title: "Green"
        // I want create my desire rectangle here instead of 'rectMain' in MyWindow
    }
}
```

So, I defined a property in MyWindow.qml like this:

```
property alias mainPart: rectMain
```

And I used it in `innerWindow` instead of commented section in main.qml:

```
Rectangle {
    width: 200

    MyWindow {
        id: innerWindow
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "lightgreen"
        title: "Green"
        mainPart: Rectangle {
            id: myDesireRect
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

But following error was happend:

> Invalid property assignment: "mainPart" is a read-only property

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you desire is a container nested inside your `MyWindow.qml` whose contents you can access or assign from outside this file. One way of doing this is to give `rectMain`'s containing `Rectangle` an id (e.g. `recMainContainer`), and then instead of the alias, declare `property Rectangle mainPart` at the top of your file. Side note, `Rectangle`s assigned to this property will not have a parent by default, but you can manage this with `onMainPartChanged`:

```
Item {
    id: root
    width: 300
    height: 300

    property alias title: txtTitle.text
    property alias color: backgroundItem.color
    property Rectangle mainPart     // new Rectangle property instead of alias

    onMainPartChanged: mainPart.parent = rectMainContainer // assign parent whenever mainPart changes

    Rectangle {
        id: backgroundItem
       //...condensed code...//

        Rectangle {
            id: rectMainContainer     // new id
            anchors.top: headerBar.bottom
            anchors.left: parent.left
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

            // removed rectMain from here
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah! That worked. @DFaller , thanks for your creative solution.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to put child items inside `rectMain`, you want to alias its `data` property.

```
property alias mainPart: rectMain.data
```

Then when you use it, you'll be able to place items inside it like this:

```
Rectangle {
    MyWindow {
        mainPart: SomeOtherItem {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need to change rectMain itself. @DFaller 's answer is true.